# How to draw a square with getting center points in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot

I want to plot several squares defined by their center points. Here is my current code:

```
x1=0;
x2=1;
y1=0;
y2=1;
x = [x1, x2, x2, x1, x1];
y = [y1, y1, y2, y2, y1];
plot(x, y, 'b-', 'LineWidth', 3);
hold on;
x1=0.25;
x2=.75;
y1=0.25;
y2=.75;
x = [x1, x2, x2, x1, x1];
y = [y1, y1, y2, y2, y1];
plot(x, y, 'b-');
xlim([-1, 2]);
ylim([-1, 2]);
```

I want to use this in the form:

```
points  = [1,4];
lengthSquare = 5;
square(points, lengthSquare);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work. It's based on a previous answer I gave for [hexagons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31356392/to-find-the-boundary-of-hexagonal-structure/31363570#31363570)

```
function square( centers, sides )
h = figure(47);
close(h)
h = figure(47);

nSides = 4; % number of sides of regular polygon
rot = 0;    % rotation angle in degrees

% every polygon has the same side length?
if length(sides) == 1
    sides = sides * ones(size(centers, 1),1);
end

x0 = centers(:,1);
y0 = centers(:,2);

filledShape = true;

[x, y] = arrayfun(@(X0, Y0, S) vertexCoords(X0, Y0, S, nSides, ~filledShape, rot), x0,y0,sides, 'uni', 0);

if filledShape
    for i = 1:length(x)
        patch('Faces', 1:length(x{i}), 'Vertices', [x{i}, y{i}],'FaceColor','red')
    end

else
    T = [x, y]';
    plot(T{:},'LineWidth',2)
end

axis equal

end

function [x, y] = vertexCoords(x0, y0, s, nSides, rot, closed)
        %Need nSides+1 to close the figure.
        theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, nSides+1)' - (pi/nSides) - rot;

    if ~closed
        theta(end) = [];
    end

    % convert from side length to diameter
    D = 2*s ./ sqrt(2 - 2*cos(2*pi/nSides));

        %Convert from polar to Cartesian coordinates 
        x = D/2 * cos(theta) + x0;
        y = D/2 * sin(theta) + y0;
end
```

Comment: how to with this fill the square?

Comment: Use `fill` or `patch` instead of `plot` if you want them filled.

Comment: I treid both of them in `square` function but shows : **Not enough input arguments**.

Comment: I made the changes to my answer but, you shouldn't just come back and say "it doesn't work" you should look at the documentation (just hit F1 on the function you are having problems with)